# Exchange program in Italy with French "D" visa

Tags: visas, exchange

I am an international student in France with a long-stay visa type D. I will be doing an exchange program in Italy for 4 months. Can I study there with my French visa or do I need any other documents?

Comment: Your 'D' visa allows you to travel to other Shengen countries but only within the 90/180 rule - you will need some other visa or permit for 4 months in Italy.